# Google Colab stuck at Fetching 19 files: 0%

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion

So i've been trying to run stable diffusion on google colab and been stuck on fetching files forever. Even yesterday this ran just fine. What might be the issue here?
Sorry I'm not an programmer. I just know a bit of python and my fair share of how to use colab.

I was expecting a smooth execution of the program and

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it in a strange way : I added a secret named HF_TOKEN (by clicking the key icon on the left). The value may be a valid HuggingFace token but not necessarily, because when it asks if I want to grant access to the HF_TOKEN secret, I cancel to deny access. It seems strange but it works (perhaps a bug ?).

Comment: This seems very bizarre, but it solved the issue for me too, thanks :p

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem.
I tried the same code on Kaggle and it worked fine, so I think it's either a temporary issue with Google Colab or its use has been restricted by Google.

(Also, an interesting change was that a warning about the HuggingFace token not being set was displayed in the log, which had not been there before. The stuck problem remains the same whether I set the token or not, but maybe I changed something on HuggingFace's side as well.)

**Edit:**
As Jacques says, I set a token named HF_TOKEN and tried running it **without** giving permissions and it worked.

**Specific steps:**

[1. Click at "Secret" tab and "Add new secret"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/461fD.png)

[2. Set the name to "HF_TOKEN" and turn off "Access from Notebook"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrGVH.png)

3.Click "Cancel" when asked for permission to access the token

(Sorry that the images are in Japanese!)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think something is it changing in the Google Calab environment because the same code was working perfectly fine the last week but now it is taking forever to load the files of the stable diffusion and I tried to add the hugging face key tokens but it didn't work!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, it doesn't look like you are answering the question. Can you familiarise with the guideline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/)